# Python-MySql ImportError: No module named 'MySQL'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sensor.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I got the above error message while trying to import mysql.connector, iam using windows and
[image]

i try to install mysql-connector-pyhton or mysql-connector-rf but still error

how i can solve this?

thanks before

Comment: try  from mysql import connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's solved :

1. uninstall python 32 bit
2. install python 64 bit
3. instal mysql-connector/mysql-connector-python
4. It's worked

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your machine has the mysql driver installed.

I know you said you had xampp version 3.2.4 installed, but I think you should go with mysql. Make sure that you have installed that specific package.

You can install the mysql package through pip, as follows:

```
pip install mysql
```